# If the api failing with connection timeout/Socket timeout , how to ignore from listener(Aggregate report) in Jmere/Blazemeter?

Tags: jmeter-5.0, blazemeter

Currently we are using below code to ignore those issues but transactions/hits is appearing in listener.

```
if (sampleResult.getResponseCode().equals("Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException") || sampleResult.getResponseCode().equals("Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException")) {
    sampleResult.setSuccessful(true); 
}
```

if api fails with connection timeout/Socket timeout , the hits should exclude from listener (Aggregate/summary report) in Jmeter & Blazemeter.

Answer (score -1):

**Answer:** Below code is working as expected:

```
def ResponseCode =prev.getResponseCode();
if (ResponseCode == "Non HTTP response code: org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException" || ResponseCode == "Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketTimeoutException") {
   prev.setIgnore()
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: Also, please [edit] your answer to include formatting of your code so it’s more readable.